# Custom controller for video that is added from editor

Tags: media

How can we control the video that is added on pages from media editor through various events like in youtube json api?

Comment: Wordpress converts the [video] shortcode into  <video> element. [HTML video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)